# How to find consecutive same values items as a Linq group

Tags: c#, linq

```
var schedules = new List<Item>{
    new Item { Id=1, Name = "S" },
    new Item { Id=2, Name = "P" },
    new Item { Id=3, Name = "X" },
    new Item { Id=4, Name = "X" },
    new Item { Id=5, Name = "P" },
    new Item { Id=6, Name = "P" },
    new Item { Id=7, Name = "P" },
    new Item { Id=8, Name = "S" }
};
```

I want to select same values and same orders in a new list like this:

```
var groupedAndSelectedList = new List<List<Item>>{
    new List<Item> {       
        new Item { Id=3, Name = "X" },
        new Item { Id=4, Name = "X" },
    },
    new List<Item> {       
        new Item { Id=5, Name = "P" },
        new Item { Id=6, Name = "P" },
        new Item { Id=7, Name = "P" },
    }
}
```

If item is single like `new Item { Id=3, Name = "A" }` I do not need to get it.

Group by selects all X or P elements in list. But I want if items stands after or before another item.

Is this possible using linq?

Comment: _If ıtem is single like new Item { Id=3_ Do you mean to skip items with Id  greater than 2?

Comment: What is the expected output if you had `new Item { Id=1, Name = "X" },` as the last item in *schedules*

Comment: You say you want consecutive items. Can you be more specific and provide more details about your requirements. What about:   `new Item { Id=1, Name = "X" },
    new Item { Id=2, Name = "X" },
    new Item { Id=3, Name = "A" },
    new Item { Id=4, Name = "X" },
    new Item { Id=5, Name = "X" },`

Comment: I updated the post example for clear understand. Group by selects all X or P elements. But I want if items stands after or before another item.

Comment: Still vague.... OK `SPXXPPPS` => `XXPPP`. What about `SPXXPPPSXX`? `XXPPPXX` or `XXXXPPP`

Comment: After the edit, your question is unclear. You need to say clearly what is the logic behind the grouping. maybe adding what you've tried.

Comment: @Eser, i think OP want to get consecuive items where `Id` is consecutive!

Comment: @MaciejLos the keyword is `i think`. We don't know exactly what is being asked here.

Comment: @L.B, Good catch!

Comment: I don't understand why this would be downvoted: it's a good question with a complete example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ambiguity?

Comment: Hey frinds, why downvoted this question? This is a clear question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for here is a `GroupWhile<T>` method.

Credit to user [L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b) for the solution. Go give his original answer an UpDoot
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20469961/30155

```
    var schedules = new List<Item>{
        new Item { Id=1, Name = "S" },
        new Item { Id=2, Name = "P" },
        new Item { Id=3, Name = "X" },
        new Item { Id=4, Name = "X" },
        new Item { Id=5, Name = "P" },
        new Item { Id=6, Name = "P" },
        new Item { Id=7, Name = "P" },
        new Item { Id=8, Name = "S" }
    };

    var results = schedules
        .GroupWhile((preceding, next) => preceding.Name == next.Name) 
        //Group items, while the next is equal to the preceding one
        .Where(s => s.Count() > 1)
        //Only include results where the generated sublist have more than 1 element.
        .ToList();

    foreach (var sublist in results)
    {
        foreach (Item i in sublist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i.Name} - {i.Id}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

You can add the implementation as an Extension Method to all `IEnumerable<T>` like so.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, T, bool> condition)
    {
        T prev = seq.First();
        List<T> list = new List<T>() { prev };

        foreach (T item in seq.Skip(1))
        {
            if (condition(prev, item) == false)
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }
            list.Add(item);
            prev = item;
        }

        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelllent solution! Your `GroupWhile` method is what i was thinking about... My first thought was about `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` methods!

Comment: The funny thing is that I have the same line-by-line code (*GroupWhile*) in my solution used to answer SO questions. I am trying to find the origin of this code :)

Comment: I can't take credit for it... I just knew the name of what you were looking for :-) I have a bag of these extension methods I've collected over the years, and I'm pretty sure I found that solution on here on SO a couple of years back. If you're interested you should check out the MoreLinq project. https://morelinq.github.io/ that's usually my first port of call when I'm looking to do something with Linq that isn't available out of the box.

Comment: @L.B right... like I said, I'm positive I found this on here 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: Found it :-) See Edit.

Comment: @EoinCampbell I really didn't know it was me. :))) +1

Comment: hah... I can barely remember the code I wrote last tuesday... you get a free pass on an SO response from 2013

Comment: Hey frinds, why downvoted this question? This is a clear question and found a good solutin.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by maintaining the count of items that you found so far. This helps you find consecutive items, because the value of `count(name) - index` is invariant for them:

```
IDictionary<string,int> count = new Dictionary<string,int>();
var groups = schedules
    .Select((s, i) => new {
        Item = s
    ,   Index = i
    })
    .GroupBy(p => {
        var name = p.Item.Name;
        int current;
        if (!count.TryGetValue(name, out current)) {
            current = 0;
            count.Add(name, current);
        }
        count[name] = current + 1;
        return new { Name = name, Order = current - p.Index };
    })
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .Where(g => g.Count > 1)
    .ToList();
```

This produces the desired output for your example:

```
{ Item = Id=3 Name=X, Index = 2 }
{ Item = Id=4 Name=X, Index = 3 }
-----
{ Item = Id=5 Name=P, Index = 4 }
{ Item = Id=6 Name=P, Index = 5 }
{ Item = Id=7 Name=P, Index = 6 }
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/Bhn2kG)

**Note:** If `Order = current - p.Index` expression looks a little like "magic", consider removing the final `Select` and `Where` clauses, and enumerating group keys.

Comment: Well.. Seems that your solution resolves future problem of "gaps and islands" related to Id ;) +1!

Answer (score 1):

@dasblinkenlight has provided an answer that just uses LINQ. Any answer using purely existing LINQ methods may be ugly, may perform poorly, and may not be highly reusable. (This is not a criticism of that answer. It's a criticism of LINQ.)

@eoin-campbell has provided an answer that uses a custom LINQ method. However, I think it can be improved upon to more closely match the capabilities of the existing LINQ `GroupBy` function, such as custom comparers (for when you need to do things like case-insensitive comparison of the keys). This `Partition` method below looks and feels like the `GroupBy` function but meets the requirement for consecutive items.

You can use this method to meet your goal by doing the following. Notice that it looks exactly like how you would write this if you didn't have the consecutivity requirement, but it's using `Partition` instead of `GroupBy`.

```
var partitionsWithMoreThan1 = schedules.Partition(o => o.Name)
                                       .Where(p => p.Count() > 1)
                                       .Select(p => p.ToList())
                                       .ToList();
```

Here's the method:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Partitions the elements of a sequence into smaller collections according to a specified
    /// key selector function, optionally comparing the keys by using a specified comparer.
    /// Unlike GroupBy, this method does not produce a single collection for each key value.
    /// Instead, this method produces a collection for each consecutive set of matching keys.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">The type of the elements of <paramref name="source"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key returned by <paramref name="keySelector"/>.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">An <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> whose elements to partition.</param>
    /// <param name="keySelector">A function to extract the key for each element.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">An <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}"/> to compare keys.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <b>IEnumerable{IGrouping{TKey, TSource}}</b> in C#
    /// or <b>IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of TKey, TSource))</b> in Visual Basic
    /// where each <see cref="IGrouping{TKey,TElement}"/> object contains a collection of objects and a key.
    /// </returns>
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> Partition<TKey, TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null)
            comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = enumerator.Current;
                var partitionKey = keySelector(item);
                var itemsInPartition = new List<TSource> {item};
                var lastPartitionKey = partitionKey;
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    item = enumerator.Current;
                    partitionKey = keySelector(item);
                    if (comparer.Equals(partitionKey, lastPartitionKey))
                    {
                        itemsInPartition.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        yield return new Grouping<TKey, TSource>(lastPartitionKey, itemsInPartition);
                        itemsInPartition = new List<TSource> {item};
                        lastPartitionKey = partitionKey;
                    }
                }
                yield return new Grouping<TKey, TSource>(lastPartitionKey, itemsInPartition);
            }
        }
    }

    // it's a shame there's no ready-made public implementation that will do this
    private class Grouping<TKey, TSource> : IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
    {
        public Grouping(TKey key, List<TSource> items)
        {
            _items = items;
            Key = key;
        }

        public TKey Key { get; }

        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        private readonly List<TSource> _items;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a Microsoft official example on how to implement this function at the same way as the native GroupBy do. The implementation is also thread safe.

Follow the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-results-by-contiguous-keys

Comment: Looking at your code I think you could improve the "generic" Grouping<Tkey, TSource> using a IEnumerable<TSource> constructor and an IEnumerable<TSource> _items field.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comment clarifications (the question is *really* unclear now), I think this is what is needed.

It uses an extension method that groups runs of keys together, `GroupByRuns`, that is based on a `GroupByWhile` the groups by testing consecutive items, which is based on `ScanPair`, which is a variation of my APL inspired `Scan` operator that is like `Aggregate`, but returns intermediate results, and uses a `ValueTuple` `(Key, Value)` to pair keys with values along the way.

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TRes>> GroupByRuns<T, TKey, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,TKey> keySelector, Func<T,TRes> resultSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null) {
    cmp = cmp ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    return src.GroupByWhile((prev, cur) => cmp.Equals(keySelector(prev), keySelector(cur)), resultSelector);
}
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByRuns<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,TKey> keySelector) => src.GroupByRuns(keySelector, e => e);
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupByRuns<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) => src.GroupByRuns(e => e, e => e);

public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TRes>> GroupByWhile<T, TRes>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T,T,bool> testFn, Func<T,TRes> resultFn) =>
    src.ScanPair(1, (kvp, cur) => testFn(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
       .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => resultFn(kvp.Value));

public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanPair<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value),T,TKey> combineFn) {
    using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (srce.MoveNext()) {
            var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

            while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                yield return prevkv;
                prevkv = (combineFn(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
            }
            yield return prevkv;
        }
    }
}
```

I realize this is a lot of extension code, but by using the general `ScanPair` base, you can build other specialized grouping methods, such as `GroupBySequential`.

Now you just `GroupByRuns` of `Name` and select the runs with more than one member, then convert each run to a `List` and the whole thing to a `List`:

```
var ans = schedules.GroupByRuns(s => s.Name)
                   .Where(sg => sg.Count() > 1)
                   .Select(sg => sg.ToList())
                   .ToList();
```

NOTE: For @Aominè, who had an interesting take on optimizing `Count() > 1` using `Take(2).Count()` or @MichaelGunter using `Skip(1).Any()`, after `GroupBy` the sub-groups (internal type `Grouping`) each implement `IList` and the `Count()` method just gets the count directly from the `Grouping.count` field.

Comment: OP says they're looking for consecutive entries. This LINQ does not check for consecutiveness.

Comment: How does your query correlate with skipping items with Id=3? What if items are not sequential?

Comment: @JohnyL OP does not state he wants to skip items with Id=3. OP is stating that, in his sample data, there is an entry `new Item { Id=3, Name = "A" }` which should be skipped because there's only one item with Name = "A".

Comment: @MichaelGunter I think OP just focalized on the ID property but the result can be get with group by Name :)

Comment: I updated the post example for clear understand. Group by selects all X or P elements. But I want if items stands  after or before another item.

Comment: @barteloma Based on your comments (the question is terribly unclear now), I have changed my answer.