# Group objects by property in C#, maintaining original order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects in C# of type `IEnumerable<BlockListItem>`. Each block list item has a string property called 'Alias'. I need to be able to group the items in sequence by their Alias. However, certain aliases should not be allowed to be grouped with others, they should be the only item in the group. The non-groupable aliases are defined as a list of strings.

Here's a written example of the original data:

```
Item 1 (alias A)
Item 2 (alias A)
Item 3 (alias B)
Item 4 (alias C)
Item 5 (alias C)
Item 6 (alias A)
Item 7 (alias A)
...etc
```

Assume that anything with the alias of C should be ungroupable.

What I want the outcome to be is:

```
Group 1
  Item 1 (alias A)
  Item 2 (alias A)
Group 2
  Item 3 (alias B)
Group 3
  Item 4 (alias C)
Group 4
  Item 5 (alias C)
Group 5
  Item 6 (alias A)
  Item 7 (alias A)
```

In need to preserve the order of the items, as per the outcome above.

Could anyone please suggest a neat way to accomplish this. I've tried Linq Grouping but that doesn't preserve the order; this custom [GroupWhile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50300125/how-to-find-consecutive-same-values-items-as-a-linq-group#answer-50300648) extension looks interesting but doesn't handle the ungroupable items and my other attempts using loops are way off.

Comment: Is using linq a requirement? If not, you could use standard operations like a loop that goes over your items and groups them sequentially. It could be much easier to filter your alias C this way.

Comment: Linq is not a requirement, no.

Comment: How about `.GroupWhile((preceding, next) => preceding.alias== next.alias && next.alias != "C") ` or `.GroupWhile( ... && !ungroupableAliases.Contains(next.alias))`?

Comment: Caution: The `GroupWhile` extension function defined in the the answer you linked appears to have a flaw where the source enumeration may be evaluated twice - once by the `.First()` and once by the `foreach (... .Skip(1))`. It's a useful extension, but there might be a better version out there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments, I find that a standard loop could be handy for this scenario.

You could create a `List<List<BlockListItem>>` variable which you populate with your groups, and a `List<BlockListItem>` variable to keep track of the current group.

If implemented in a method, it could look like:

```
private static List<List<BlockListItem>> GroupItems(
    IEnumerable<BlockListItem> items,
    string[] ungroupableAliases)
{
    if (items == null || !items.Any())
    {
        return new List<List<BlockListItem>>();
    }

    var itemGroups = new List<List<BlockListItem>>();
    var currentItemGroup = new List<BlockListItem> { items.First() };

    var currentItemGroupAlias = items.First().Alias;
    
    foreach (var item in items.Skip(1))
    {
        var itemIsGroupable =
            item.Alias == currentItemGroupAlias && !ungroupableAliases.Contains(item.Alias);

        if (!itemIsGroupable)
        {
            itemGroups.Add(currentItemGroup.ToList());
            currentItemGroup.Clear();

            currentItemGroupAlias = item.Alias;
        }
        
        currentItemGroup.Add(item);
    }
    
    itemGroups.Add(currentItemGroup.ToList());
    
    return itemGroups;
}
```

and be used as follows:

```
var ungroupableAliases = new[] { "C" };

IEnumerable<BlockListItem> items = new List<BlockListItem>
{
    new() { Id = 1, Alias = "A" },
    new() { Id = 2, Alias = "A" },
    new() { Id = 3, Alias = "B" },
    new() { Id = 4, Alias = "C" },
    new() { Id = 5, Alias = "C" },
    new() { Id = 6, Alias = "A" },
    new() { Id = 7, Alias = "A" },
};

var groupedItems = GroupItems(items, ungroupableAliases);
```

Depending on how specific the groups need to be designed (e.g. including group number, which is not covered in this approach), you may want to customize the implementation.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IhEmnd) is a fiddle to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

A possible rudimentary solution that's somewhat generic and doesn't require a huge amount of re-allocations:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions 
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TEntity>> Cluster<TEntity, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TEntity> enumerable,
        Func<TEntity, TKey> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) 
    {
        TKey lastKey = default(TKey);
        LinkedList<TEntity> entries = new LinkedList<TEntity>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in enumerable) 
        {
            var key = keySelector(item);
            if (i > 0 && !comparer.Equals(key, lastKey)) 
            {
                yield return entries;
                entries = new LinkedList<TEntity>();
            }
            entries.AddLast(item);
            lastKey = key;
            i++;
        }
    
        if (entries.Any())
            yield return entries;
    }
}


class ExcludingComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> 
{
    public bool Equals(string a, string b) 
    {
        return a == b && a != "C";  
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string val) => val.GetHashCode();
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
new string[] { "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A" }
    .Select(x => new Item(x))
    .Cluster(x => x.Alias, new ExcludingComparer())
```

`IEqualityComparer` may not be super semantically correct to use here, but you can sub something in to replace it as you like.