# Sublists of consecutive elements that fit a condition in a list c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

So suppose we have a parking(represented as a dictionary<int,bool> :
Every parking lot has its id and a boolean(free,filled).
This way:

```
Dictionary<int,bool> parking..
parking[0]= true // means that the first parking lot is free
```

My question is i want to get the all sublist of consecutive elements that matchs in a condition : parking-lot is free.

First i can get elements that fits in this condition easy:

```
parking.Where(X => X.Value).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

But then using linq operations i dont know how to get the first generated list that matchs in.
Can i do this without thousand of foreach-while loops checking iterating one by one, is there a easier way with linq?

This method gets a list of consecutive free parking lots
data:
0-free,
1-free,
2-filled ,
3-free
The results will be two lists:
First One will contain => 0 ,1
Second One will contain=> 3
These are the list of consecutive of parking lots that are free.

```
public List<List<int>> ConsecutiveParkingLotFree(int numberOfConsecutive){}
```

Comment: "I don't know how to get the first generated list that matches in." I haven't got a clue what you mean. Consider to edit the question and provide a proper requirement

Comment: @JonasH yeah sorry i corrected it sorry . Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely, you can use the `Aggregate` method

Comment: Ok i tried to clarify the example @Error404Brainnotfound

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse i mean a list of consecutive elements that fit in a condition. The condition is that the parkinglot is free. So i want to get a list of consecutive free parking lots.

Comment: This is much clearer, thank you @hesolar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write your own helper function to do things like this. For example

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GroupSequential<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> self,
    Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    using var enumerator = self.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var current = enumerator.Current;
        var oldValue = condition(current);
        if (oldValue)
        {
            list.Add(current);
        }
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            current = enumerator.Current;
            var newValue = condition(current);
            if (newValue)
            {
                list.Add(current);
            }
            else if (oldValue)
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }
            oldValue = newValue;
        }

        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

This will put all the items with a true-value in a list. When a true->false transition is encountered the list is returned and recreated. I would expect that there are more compact ways to write functions like this, but it should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply GroupWhile solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20469961/13506569).

```
parking.Where(X => X.Value)
.Select(x => x.Key)
.GroupWhile((x, y) => y - x == 1)
.ToList()
```